# Interface type in method, how do I access it?

Tags: java, generics, interface, compareto

I would like to define a custom Interface "Sorting" with a custom compareTo method

```
public class Testing implements Sorting{

    public static void main(String [] args){
        Testing x1 = new Testing (4);
        Testing x2 = new Testing (5);
        System.out.println(x1.compareTo(x2));
    }
    private final int x;

    public Testing(int x){
        this.x= x;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Sorting s) {

        if(this == s)
        return 0;
        if(this.x> ((Testing) s).x) return 1;
        if(this.x<((Testing) s).x) return -1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I don't know how to access said compareTo method to compare the values, but I would like to be able to use this for ints, for Strings and all kinds of types that fit to Sorting.

Also, does

```
public class Testing<Integer> implements Sorting<Integer>{..}
```

help any bit if I use Testing for int only?

Edit: Thank you for the replies, I want to point out that I **can't** use Comparable.
To be more exact: I want to compare two objects, one is of Testing type, the other one is of type "Sorting" which is given to the method. How can I convert Sorting into the Testing type while still being able to compare those two?

Edit2: I think I managed it, I'll update the code above and then you can maybe understand what I'm struggling with, I still don't know **why** that exactly is possible, but it seems to work.

Comment: You could sort any type that implements IComparable. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html
Any type you can compare, you can sort. see https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/

Comment: Is there a reason why you are writing your own interface for this when `Comparable` already exists?

Comment: It's pretty odd to put your main method in a class that is used for any other purpose. I mean you can do it, but that means you still need to instantiate a Testing object.

Comment: Right now, you would need to do `Testing testing = new Testing()` which would have no fields or anything. Then you could do `testing.compareTo(anotherSorting)` but it would always return 0.

Comment: I guess what I"m getting at is that it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Like, do you understand that Interfaces only apply to objects and your main method has nothing to do with an object right now?

Comment: `public class Testing<Integer> implements Sorting<Integer>` makes `Integer` a generic parameter, which should have been named with a single uppercase letter. As shown, it's confusingly​ similar to a standard concrete type name from the standard API. Either rename the generic parameter, or if you do mean to use the concrete type, don't put it in a place that makes it a generic parameter.

Comment: Were you thinking that `Testing` too should be a generic class handling integers, strings and other types? I think you’ll have quite a challenge figuring out how to implement a `compareTo` method that will handle any (reference) type.

Comment: Maybe it will be easier to help if you can give us the bigger picture: what do you want to use this interface and this class for?

Comment: Thanks for the replies so far, I see that I wasn't clear enough.

@Novaterata 
The reason the main is there is just so I can access the compareTo somehow, it could be anyhwere else aswell.

Comment: @Radiodef 
I want to implement it myself because it is a task, but that's just a small part of it. I don't even seek for finished code but understanding the function/ implementation of the method.

Comment: @Lew Bloch 
I would like to use the standard types which already exist, but I thought it would ensure the type is being used in the object by writing Sorting<Integer>

Comment: @Ole V.V.

I want this compareTo method to take everything that fits "Sorting" and be able to sort it through. 
Now I don't know how to compare 2 objects using < <=  and > since it is defined for the primitive types, but my Sorting object obviously isn't one.

This is a problem which is connected to a bigger missunderstanding from my side and I would like to understand and resolve it.

Comment: Your Sorting interface is exactly the same as Comparable. Comparable is already implemented by lots of classes. Just use Comparable. For your own classes, just have them implement Comparable

Comment: You can also just create a temporary Comparable with a lambda like `Comparable<Integer> myIntComparable = i -> i.compareTo(anIntVariable);`

Comment: Please look up the Stream sorted method and the Comparator and Comparable Interfaces used by it

Comment: Making it the generic parameter in `Testing<Integer> ` made what you wanted not happen.

Comment: @Novaterata Thank you for the suggestions, I would gladly implement the Comparable interface (especially that lambda function, looks really neat) but I'm forced to avoid it for the task.
That's why I'm not understanding how I can use the "Sorting s" in the method, since I can't create any Sorting object, so it must be another type instead of Sorting, is this correct?

Comment: @Lew Bloch Ah so I should only use it when I'm absolutely sure I only need that type in the class?

Comment: No, what you should do is understand the syntax of generic declarations, particularly​ the difference between a generic parameter and a specific type usage. Check out the Tutorial.

Comment: Think in terms of Interfaces, Testing should be an implementation of `Sorting<Integer>`, so it can compareTo any `Sorting<Integer>` and you should use the Interface type for your variables not the implementation type, and a lambda can be a Sorting implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Interfaces not the concrete types. That way you can mix different concrete types that implement the same interface.

Either you have to change to compareTo(V other) or you have to add something more to your interface like this:

```
public interface Sorting <V> {
    V getValue();   
    int compareTo(Sorting<V> other);
}

public class Testing implements Sorting<Integer>{

    public static void main(String [] args){
        Sorting<Integer> x1 = new Testing (4);
        Sorting<Integer> x2 = new Testing (5);
        System.out.println(String.format("compareTo is %d", x1.compareTo(x2));
    }

    private final int value;

    public Testing(int value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    int getValue(){
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Sorting<Integer> other) {
        int otherValue = other.getValue();
        if(value > otherValue)
            return 1;
        else if(value < otherValue)
            return -1;
        return 0; // must be ==
    }
}
```

Note that you don't really gain much by doing `compareTo(Sorting<Integer> other)` as opposed to `compareTo(Integer other)` as the other's implementation isn't important, which is why Comparable does just that. You also won't be able to use a lambda now as your interface has 2 abstract methods, you can still use an anonymous class though.

```
 int someInt = 12344;
 x1.compareTo(new Sorting<Integer>() {
    @Override int getValue(){ return someInt; }
    @Override int compareTo(Sorting<Integer> other) { return 0; }// who cares isn't used
}
```

Comment: @mxOx2kL If this isn't what you want, you just haven't explained what you do want. You said you CAN'T use Comparable, but you don't explain why. That implies this is homework, we need to know what exactly you have to do to solve that problem.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to explain it in such detail, many things got clearer after that and yeah, it's a homework but there's more to it, I just got stuck at that and didn't quite wrap my head around this.

What I still don't understand is:

You say that using the compareTo ( Sorting<Integer> other)  doesn't make my life easier, I think that counts for compareTo(Sorting other) aswell? Isn't it more flexible than passing an Integer?

Also, the reason I insisted on avoiding the Comparable interface is cause we have certain restrictions, similar to compareTo(Sorting s)

Comment: So I need to use the exact syntax for the method. The thing is that I don't understand how I can still pass the Integer as Sorting to the method since I didn't explicitly define anything in the Sorting interface itself.

Comment: You can't, the way you have it written.

Comment: `Sorting` is just `Sorting<V>` minus the generic information and should never be used as it just turns everything into an Object. You need to understand that objects have an Interface that limits what is visible to the outside world. If the interface is only `int compareTo(Sortable<V> other)` then you literally have no information you can use that's useful. How could you sort? Your choices are to add more to the interface or use V as the interface parameter.

Comment: Okay now I understand, so there is no real reasoning behind doing it this way besides having to carefully cast everything in the compareTo method, which is pretty dangerous.

The interface parameter would then limit which type could be used on the object, right? I'm currently looking into some tutorials and that seems to be the case, as far as I can see.

Having no idea how to sort was exactly my problem, I have to cast my Sorting object to fit the class-object so I can compare those, I don't know if that's intended but it seems to be quite a hassle.